# Better developer tool for IE (with contraints)

Tags: internet-explorer, http, firefox, https, fiddler

I am trying to find a tool to use that is comparable to the network tab of the Firefox developer tools. The site I am trying to monitor only partially works with Firefox, therefore to continue I need to do this with IE. I have IE 8 on my machine but the developer tools for IE do not seem to include this feature. I have tried Fiddler but the site I am working with requires a log in and then goes to an https page. For some reason Fiddler no longer works after the login but Firefox's tools continue to work. I understand that an upgraded version of IE may have better developer tools and I also looked into Wireshark. Unfortunately, I am heavily restricted on this computer so updating IE is actually not possible and downloading Wireshark would be a headache. Have I overlooked something? What is the best solution? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Fiddler should work. Did you turn on the “Capture HTTPS CONNECTs” option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Fiddler, enable HTTPS in Fiddler's settings, then go to localhost:8888 in the browser and download/install Fiddler's root certificate.

(Note: You should preferably remove this certificate again when you're done - having Fiddler's fake root certificate installed could allow attackers to spoof HTTPS websites or do man-in-the-middle attacks against you. You've been warned!).

Comment: Removing the certificate is not really necessary; see `What's the risk` here: http://blogs.telerik.com/fiddler/posts/13-08-19/faq---certificates-in-fiddler

Comment: Thanks EricLaw - that post is great!